# Como inicializar um array em Kotlin?

Tags: array, kotlin

Preciso inicializar um array em Kotlin mais não sei como fazer, em Java eu fiz assim:

```
int numeros[] = new int[] {0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 6):

A forma mais comum é esta:

```
val numeros : IntArray = intArrayOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Mas também pode ser:

```
val numeros = Array(10, { i -> i })
```

Aqui:

```
import java.util.*
 
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val numeros: IntArray = intArrayOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    val numeros2 = Array(10, { i -> i })
    println(Arrays.toString(numeros))
    println(Arrays.toString(numeros2))
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BL9WUz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ppyhaykn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/ArrayInit.kt).

Comment: Eu já ia falar do `IntArray` :] - ps: ByteArray e ShortArray também :P, mas já corrigiu hehehe. PS: o segundo me soa mais interessante por poder após ao arrow inserir os valores dinamicamente conforme o interesse. +1

Comment: codingground com erro: `timeout: failed to run command ‘kotlinc’: Permission denied`, deve ser bug deles. ps: não estou logado neles

Comment: consigo no Java fazer o array dinamico, igual vc fez?

Comment: Na mão consegue, e pode criar uma função para isto :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento por isso que coloco em lugares diferentes, tem sempre um falhando :)

Comment: @MatheusHenrique depende do que é dinamico pra ti, como eu expliquei ali acima, o interessante da segunda forma com arrow `->` é passar o valor que desejar gerando conforme necessitar, já que o `i` ali após o `->` é apenas um exemplo, poderia ser qualquer coisa :)

Answer (score 1):

Como a pergunta não é especificamente para array de Int, embora seja incluído no exemplo, assim criamos **arrays de objetos** em kotlin:

```
val arrayOfStrings = arrayOf("A", "B", "C")
val arrayOfFoo = arrayOf(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3))
```

e assim por diante.

A assinatura do método arrayOf é:

```
inline fun <reified T> arrayOf(vararg elements: T): Array<T>
```

Com essa função você pode criar arrays de quaisquer tipos.

---

### No entanto

Para Arrays de tipos primitivos(int, double, short, ...), é recomendado que você use funções especiais, que seguem uma assinatura semelhante:

```
val arrayOfInts = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val arrayOfDoubles = doubleArrayOf(1.0, 1.1, 1.2)
```